# Como traduzir "Beyond desolation"?

Tags: tradução

[Beyond Desolation](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OB09mmZvlsw) é a última trilha original de The Last Of Us Part II e diz muito sobre o estado que se encontra uma das protagonistas ao final do jogo. Frequentemente fico pensando em como poderia ser traduzido da melhor forma possível para o português, considerando que *beyond* parece significar tanto física quanto simbolicamente, e *desolation* tanto sobre o lugar em que se encontra como o emocional da personagem. O sentido é algo como "Mais que Desolação", mas o mais próximo seria "Além de Desolação"...

Answer (score 3):

Eu até consigo entender o *além de desolação* nesse sentido, mas não me satisfaz completamente, porque me sugere também ’desolação e algo mais’. *Além de* é muito usado neste sentido, ’juntamente com, não só’:

> Além de desolação, havia também o remorso
>
> Além de estúpido, é também invejoso

Uma alternativa é ***para lá de desolação***, que não tem esta última interpretação. A seguir a “ele é para lá de estúpido”, não esperaríamos “é também invejoso”. Esperaríamos algo como:

> Ele é para lá de estúpido; é completamente imbecil

É esta noção que se pretende no *beyond desolation*. Noutros contextos, *além de* serve perfeitamente: “aquilo foi além da estupidez; chegou à imbecilidade pura”. Aqui creio que é o verbo *ir* que dá a noção desejada a *além de*.

Estou um bocado indeciso em relação a *mais que desolação*. Parece-me menos ambíguo que *além de desolação*, mas mesmo assim gosto mais de *para lá de*. Podes ainda ir para uma metáfora diferente, afastando-te da tradução literal: *nas profundezas da desolação* ou *nos abismos da desolação*.

Comment: Não sei, mas faz sentido para mim esse "algo mais" pairando em *Além de desolação*. De qualquer forma, essa construção não necessariamente precisa de um complemento e funciona sozinha. *Para lá de desolação* é bom, apesar de não soar tão elegante.

Comment: @Atilio, Eu juntei os complementos só para clarificar os vários sentidos de *além de*. Se gostas da noção de ’desolação e outras coisas também’, então *além de* é ideal. Na minha experiência algo como *beyond desolation* significa que passamos para lá da/de desolação: ou que nos livramos dela (que não é o que interessa) ou que chegamos a algo mais desolador que desolação, como se tivéssemos rebentado a escala. Eu não conheço o jogo, mas foi esta última interpretação que eu tirei da pergunta, e fiquei ainda mais convencido depois de ouvir a música: aquilo é mais chorado que um fado chorado.

Answer (score 0):

Também não vejo possibilidade melhor, apenas sugeriria uma leve mudança, a adição do artigo:

> Além da desolação

em parte porque "além de" é mais próximo de *besides*.

Comment: Inicialmente, me peguei pensando na diferença entre *"Além **de** desolação"* e *"Além **da** desolação"*. Tenho a leve impressão de que *"Além da desolação"* também traz um sentido de que a desolação estaria "superada", "deixada para trás" ou "impossibilitada", como em *"fulano está além da salvação"* ou então *"beyond recognition"*. Se tive outra ideia, não lembro.